# Select statement An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am tring to do a search on lastname and firstname with the autocomplete ajax control. But I am getting the error An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. Any idea what I am doing wrong? There error is occuring at the Words(0) line.
Thanks!

```
Public Function GetCompletionList(prefixText As String, count As Integer, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
    Try
        Dim words As String() = prefixText.Split(New Char() {","c})
        Dim Con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Con = New SqlConnection
        Dim test As String
        test = contextKey
        Con.ConnectionString = ""
        Con.Open()

        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = Con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NPI, [Entity Type Code], [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)], [Provider First Name],[Provider First Line Business Mailing Address], [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name], [Provider Business Mailing Address State Name], [Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code] FROM NPIData WHERE ([Provider Business Mailing Address State Name] = @State) AND ('" & words(0) & "','" & words(1) & "' LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%') ORDER BY [Provider First Name]"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provider", prefixText)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", contextKey)
        Dim customers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        While reader.Read
            customers.Add(reader("Provider Last Name (Legal Name)").ToString + ", " + reader("Provider First Name").ToString + "   " + reader("Provider First Line Business Mailing Address").ToString + "  " + reader("Provider Business Mailing Address City Name").ToString + ", " + reader("Provider Business Mailing Address State Name").ToString + "  " + reader("Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code").ToString + "  " + reader("NPI").ToString)

        End While


        Con.Close()

        Return customers.ToArray
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Your code results in a query like this: `SELECT ... FROM NPIData WHERE ([Provider Business Mailing Address State Name] = @State) AND ('word_1','word_2' LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%') ORDER BY [Provider First Name]` (select list omitted for brevity) Look at the part with the `LIKE`. That is invalid SQL. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Can you print the text assigned to cmd.CommandText?

Comment: I just tried running it again and got Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I am trying to be able to search on lastname, first name. Somehow I need to split out the "," hence why I have Dim words As String() = prefixText.Split(New Char() {","c})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line where you say you are failing you have

```
('" & words(0) & "','" & words(1) & "' LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%')
```

If word(0) contains txt1 and worda (1) contains txt2, this evaluates to

`'txt1','txt2'` LIKE ...

You can't compare a comma seperated list of strings with LIKE.

I don't know if you intended to concatenate words(0) and words(1) to get

`'txt1txt2' LIKE` ...

which would require

```
('" & words(0) & words(1) & "' LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%')
```

or make seperate comparisons, which would require

```
('" & words(0) & "' LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%' OR ' & words(1) & "' LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%')
```

Comment: Something not right in the single and double quotes in my answer, too, I think, but hopefully it is good enough to show the problem.